# Applet is not working in browser

Tags: java, browser, netbeans, applet, japplet

I try launch Applet in browser, but it is now working.
In AppletViewer everything is ok.
I coppied file .html to scr folder, and try to open them, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` saying that `PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet.class` can't be found:

[image]

Code from html file

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Code from java file:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {
...
```

Comment: have you kept the PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet.class in the same directory as HTML ?

Comment: Do you have more than one class? If so you need to call the jar file.

Comment: Yeah, I both file are in src folder.

Comment: It's best to put the actual **text** of the error message in the question, especially if you don't have enough rep to post pictures inline yet. That way, people know what's going on even without following the link to the picture and without someone like me coming along to put it inline for you.

Comment: `src folder`? I suppose it should be put in `bin folder`.

Comment: My mistake, I moved to build\classes folder, where I have my class file, and now I have this: http://screenshooter.net/1508970/mhvkndj

Comment: 1) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I moved to build\classes folder, where I have my class file, and now I have this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I run java applets, I put the .class files in the same folder that the .html is. When you do this, dont use the `codebase='classes'`, because it means that your class files is located in a folder called 'classes' and it wont work.